# Draw butterfly graph on html canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, math, graph, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a graph in a shape of a butterfly on html canvas using javascript. Parametric equations of the graph are:

- x=(e^(cost) -2cos4t+sin^5( t/12))sint
- y=(e^(cost) -2cos4t+sin^5( t/12))cost
- t e [0, 20.5]

I have been trying but i can't figure it out. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please add something that shows your previous efforts. You can even use the code snippets functionality to embed running code in your question. Show at least how you would draw a circle or a square...

Comment: There's nothing to show unfortunately. I'm pretty new in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of a Lissajous curve for drawing a parametrized 2D curve on a javascript canvas. You should be able to adapt this for your curve

```js
// get the handles and info on the HTML elements 
var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// construct a local coordinate system that is 
// slightly larger than [-1,1]x[-1,1]
context.translate(width/2, height/2);
context.scale(width/2.1, height/2.1);
context.lineWidth = 0.02;

// construct and draw the curve
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0,0);
for(var x = 0; x < 6*Math.PI; x += 0.05)
    context.lineTo(Math.sin(3*x),Math.sin(4*x));
context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="Canvas" width = "200" height = "200" />
```